# Let f,g $\in$ End(V). If fg = gf, then f and g are linearly dependent in the vector space End(V).

Tags: linear-algebra

> If $\Bbb K$ is a field and $V$ is a $2$-dimensional subspace on $K$. Let $f, g \in \mbox{End}(V)$. If $fg = gf$, then $f$ and $g$ are linearly dependent in the vector space $\mbox{End}(V)$.

I don't really see how to tackle this (simple) true/false question. Can anyone give a hint here?

Comment: What if $f$ is in the center of $End(V)$ (for example, it is a scalar matrix)? Does it imply that every other $g$ is a scalar matrix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is false. Let $f=\mathbb{id}_V$ and let $g$ by such that $g \neq \alpha\cdot \mathbb{id}_V$ for any $\alpha$. That is, $g$ is not just multiplication by a scalar; such endomorphisms exist since $V$ is two-dimensional (for example, pick a basis and let $g$ swap the basis vectors).

Clearly $g$ and $\mathbb{id}_V$ are linear independent (by definition of $g$). But, since $\mathbb{id}_V$ commutes with any endomorphism, we have $fg=gf$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $g$ the identity function $V\to V.$